# Strange behavior when integrating vector valued piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector, piecewise

The following straightforward integral should clearly equal $\{0,0\}$ for any $R\in\mathbb R$:

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{{1,1},x < 1}},{0,0}]Piecewise[{{x,1<x<R}},0],{x,0,2}]
```

Strangely, Mathematica outputs a piecewise expression
$$\begin{cases}\{0,0\},&R\leq1\\\{\{0,0\},\{0,0\}\},&\text{true}.\end{cases}$$
Somehow it gets the wrong type of object when $R>1$.

This error persists if the assumption $R\in\mathbb R$ is added, or if you fiddle with the other integration bounds, or if either one of the `Piecewise` functions is replaced by an equivalent `If`. Funnily, if both are replaced by `If` then it works. However this minimal example was obtained from a more complicated expression where even with two `If`s it breaks.

If anyone knows the cause of this bug I would be interested. I suppose integrating lists is not such a natural thing for Mathematica...

Comment: If you do 2 separate integrations, one for `R<=1` and one for `R>1` you get the following   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGujE.png)  on V 13.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the assumption `0*x==0` is baked into Mathematica at quite a low level.  Consequently, I think you have expressions that are sometimes evaluated as a vector and sometimes a scalar.

If you ensure that your expressions always evaluate as two element vectors, you may avoid the problem.  For example

```
Integrate[
 Piecewise[{{{1, 1}, x < 1}}, {0, 0}] 
 Piecewise[{{{x, x}, 1 < x < R}}, {0, 0}], {x, 0, 2}]
(* {0, 0} *)
```

As an example of the odd things that can happen when summing things that might be scalars or vectors, I offer the following:

```
((0 + {0, 0}) + c) /. c -> {0, 0}
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{{1, 1}, x < 1}}, {0, 0}] x Boole[1 < x < R] , {x, 0,2}]
(* {0,0} *)
```